# ngx-bootstrap - close popover after cursor leaves the popover itself

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I have the following structure, using **[ngx-bootstrap popovers with custom triggers](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#triggers-custom)**, and everything seems to be working great, except the part where I want to close the popover after there is a **mouseleave** event on the popover itself.

How can I do that?

```
<div [popover]="popTemplate" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></div>

<ng-template #popTemplate>
    <p>Popover content.</p>
    <button type="submit">Click me</button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: check my answer if you looking for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your popover content in a div and the use `(mouseleave)` event on that div to hide the popover manually.

Here is the code

```
<div [popover]="popTemplate" #pop="bs-popover" style="background-color:black" triggers="" (mouseenter)="pop.show()">This is a test</div>

<ng-template #popTemplate>
  <div (mouseleave)="pop.hide()">
    <p>Popover content.</p>
    <button type="submit">Click me</button>
  </div>     
</ng-template>
```

Here is a sample demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-rtrgyr?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thanks @Niladri , this works, but I get some unwanted behavior - when I move the cursor near the ends of the popover it disappears, and it does it randomly.